# MpAndroidChart CombinedChart - How to prevent LineData circles being drawn over Bubble data?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I have been playing with the official [CombinedChartActivity example](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/CombinedChartActivity.java) to show 2 line charts, 1 bar chart and some bubble data.

Despite having changed the `DrawOrder`...

```
mChart.setDrawOrder(new DrawOrder[]{
        DrawOrder.BAR, DrawOrder.CANDLE, DrawOrder.LINE, DrawOrder.SCATTER, DrawOrder.BUBBLE
});
```

...my Bubbles are still getting drawn over by the line circles. As you can see in this screenshot, the *lines* are correctly appearing behind the bubbles; It's just the line ***circles*** that are appearing in front of the bubbles:

[image]

How to make the circles behave like their lines, so they also appear behind the bubbles?

Here's my full Activity code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.CombinedChart.DrawOrder;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.AxisBase;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.Legend;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.XAxis.XAxisPosition;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.components.YAxis;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BarEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BubbleData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BubbleDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.BubbleEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.CandleData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.CandleDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.CandleEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.CombinedData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.ScatterData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.ScatterDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.formatter.IAxisValueFormatter;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.IDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.graphics.Typeface;

public class MpAndroidChartCombinedActivity extends Activity {

    private CombinedChart mChart;
    private final int itemcount = 12;

    protected String[] mMonths = new String[] {
            "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec"
    };

    protected String[] mParties = new String[] {
            "Party A", "Party B", "Party C", "Party D", "Party E", "Party F", "Party G", "Party H",
            "Party I", "Party J", "Party K", "Party L", "Party M", "Party N", "Party O", "Party P",
            "Party Q", "Party R", "Party S", "Party T", "Party U", "Party V", "Party W", "Party X",
            "Party Y", "Party Z"
    };

    protected Typeface mTfRegular;
    protected Typeface mTfLight;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mp_android_chart_combined);

        //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mTfRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
        mTfLight = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "OpenSans-Light.ttf");

        /**
         * Get chart reference.
         */
        CombinedChart mChart = (CombinedChart)findViewById(R.id.mpAndroidChart);

        mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        mChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
        mChart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(false);

        // draw bars behind lines
        mChart.setDrawOrder(new DrawOrder[]{
                DrawOrder.BAR, DrawOrder.CANDLE, DrawOrder.LINE, DrawOrder.SCATTER, DrawOrder.BUBBLE
        });

        Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setWordWrapEnabled(true);
        l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.BOTTOM);
        l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
        l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.HORIZONTAL);
        l.setDrawInside(false);

        YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
        rightAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        rightAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

        YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {
                return mMonths[(int) value % mMonths.length];
            }
        });

        CombinedData data = new CombinedData();

        data.setData(generateLineData());
        //data.setData(generateLineData("Line DataSet 2", Color.rgb(255, 0, 0)));
        //data.setData(generateLineData("Line DataSet 3", Color.rgb(0, 255, 0)));
        data.setData(generateBarData());
        data.setData(generateBubbleData());
        data.setData(generateScatterData());
        //data.setData(generateCandleData());
        data.setValueTypeface(mTfLight);

        xAxis.setAxisMaximum(data.getXMax() + 0.25f);

        mChart.setData(data);
        mChart.invalidate();

    }

    private LineData generateLineData() {

        LineData lineData = new LineData();

        ArrayList<Entry> entries1 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++) {
            entries1.add(new Entry(index + 0.5f, getRandom(15, 5)));
        }
        int color1 = Color.rgb(240, 238, 70);
        String dataSetLabel1 = "Line Data 1";
        LineDataSet lineDataSet1 = new LineDataSet(entries1, dataSetLabel1);
        lineDataSet1.setColor(color1);
        lineDataSet1.setLineWidth(2.5f);
        lineDataSet1.setCircleColor(color1);
        lineDataSet1.setCircleRadius(5f);
        lineDataSet1.setFillColor(color1);
        lineDataSet1.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
        lineDataSet1.setDrawValues(true);
        lineDataSet1.setValueTextSize(10f);
        lineDataSet1.setValueTextColor(color1);
        lineDataSet1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        lineData.addDataSet(lineDataSet1);

        ArrayList<Entry> entries2 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++) {
            entries2.add(new Entry(index + 0.5f, getRandom(15, 6)));
        }
        int color2 = Color.rgb(240, 0, 0);
        String dataSetLabel2 = "Line Data 2";
        LineDataSet lineDataSet2 = new LineDataSet(entries2, dataSetLabel2);
        lineDataSet2.setColor(color2);
        lineDataSet2.setLineWidth(2.5f);
        lineDataSet2.setCircleColor(color2);
        lineDataSet2.setCircleRadius(5f);
        lineDataSet2.setFillColor(color2);
        lineDataSet2.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
        lineDataSet2.setDrawValues(true);
        lineDataSet2.setValueTextSize(10f);
        lineDataSet2.setValueTextColor(color2);
        lineDataSet2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
        lineData.addDataSet(lineDataSet2);

        ArrayList<Entry> entries3 = new ArrayList<Entry>();
        for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++) {
            entries3.add(new Entry(index + 0.5f, getRandom(100, 150)));
        }
        int color3 = Color.rgb(0, 0, 255);
        String dataSetLabel3 = "Line Data 3";
        LineDataSet lineDataSet3 = new LineDataSet(entries3, dataSetLabel3);
        lineDataSet3.setColor(color3);
        lineDataSet3.setLineWidth(2.5f);
        lineDataSet3.setCircleColor(color3);
        lineDataSet3.setCircleRadius(5f);
        lineDataSet3.setFillColor(color3);
        lineDataSet3.setMode(LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER);
        lineDataSet3.setDrawValues(false);
        lineDataSet3.setValueTextSize(10f);
        lineDataSet3.setValueTextColor(color3);
        lineDataSet3.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.RIGHT);
        lineData.addDataSet(lineDataSet3);

        return lineData;
    }

    private BarData generateBarData() {

        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
        ArrayList<BarEntry> entries2 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

        for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++) {
            entries1.add(new BarEntry(0, getRandom(25, 25)));

            // stacked
            entries2.add(new BarEntry(0, new float[]{getRandom(13, 12), getRandom(13, 12)}));
        }

        BarDataSet lineDataSet1 = new BarDataSet(entries1, "Bar 1");
        lineDataSet1.setColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
        lineDataSet1.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(60, 220, 78));
        lineDataSet1.setValueTextSize(10f);
        lineDataSet1.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

        BarDataSet lineDataSet2 = new BarDataSet(entries2, "");
        lineDataSet2.setStackLabels(new String[]{"Stack 1", "Stack 2"});
        lineDataSet2.setColors(new int[]{Color.rgb(61, 165, 255), Color.rgb(23, 197, 255)});
        lineDataSet2.setValueTextColor(Color.rgb(61, 165, 255));
        lineDataSet2.setValueTextSize(10f);
        lineDataSet2.setAxisDependency(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);

        float groupSpace = 0.06f;
        float barSpace = 0.02f; // x2 dataset
        float barWidth = 0.45f; // x2 dataset
        // (0.45 + 0.02) * 2 + 0.06 = 1.00 -> interval per "group"

        BarData d = new BarData(lineDataSet1, lineDataSet2);
        d.setBarWidth(barWidth);

        // make this BarData object grouped
        d.groupBars(0, groupSpace, barSpace); // start at x = 0

        return d;
    }

    protected ScatterData generateScatterData() {

        ScatterData d = new ScatterData();

        ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

        for (float index = 0; index < itemcount; index += 0.5f)
            entries.add(new Entry(index + 0.25f, getRandom(10, 55)));

        ScatterDataSet set = new ScatterDataSet(entries, "Scatter DataSet");
        set.setColors(ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS);
        set.setScatterShapeSize(7.5f);
        set.setDrawValues(false);
        set.setValueTextSize(10f);
        d.addDataSet(set);

        return d;
    }

    protected CandleData generateCandleData() {

        CandleData d = new CandleData();

        ArrayList<CandleEntry> entries = new ArrayList<CandleEntry>();

        for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index += 2)
            entries.add(new CandleEntry(index + 1f, 90, 70, 85, 75f));

        CandleDataSet set = new CandleDataSet(entries, "Candle DataSet");
        set.setDecreasingColor(Color.rgb(142, 150, 175));
        set.setShadowColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        set.setBarSpace(0.3f);
        set.setValueTextSize(10f);
        set.setDrawValues(false);
        d.addDataSet(set);

        return d;
    }

    protected BubbleData generateBubbleData() {

        BubbleData bd = new BubbleData();

        ArrayList<BubbleEntry> entries = new ArrayList<BubbleEntry>();

        for (int index = 0; index < itemcount; index++) {
            float y = getRandom(10, 105);
            float size = getRandom(100, 105);
            entries.add(new BubbleEntry(index + 0.5f, y, size));
        }

        BubbleDataSet set = new BubbleDataSet(entries, "Bubble DataSet");
        set.setColors(ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS);
        set.setValueTextSize(10f);
        set.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        set.setHighlightCircleWidth(1.5f);
        set.setDrawValues(true);
        bd.addDataSet(set);

        return bd;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.combined, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.actionToggleLineValues: {
                for (IDataSet set : mChart.getData().getDataSets()) {
                    if (set instanceof LineDataSet)
                        set.setDrawValues(!set.isDrawValuesEnabled());
                }

                mChart.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.actionToggleBarValues: {
                for (IDataSet set : mChart.getData().getDataSets()) {
                    if (set instanceof BarDataSet)
                        set.setDrawValues(!set.isDrawValuesEnabled());
                }

                mChart.invalidate();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.actionRemoveDataSet: {

                int rnd = (int) getRandom(mChart.getData().getDataSetCount(), 0);
                mChart.getData().removeDataSet(mChart.getData().getDataSetByIndex(rnd));
                mChart.getData().notifyDataChanged();
                mChart.notifyDataSetChanged();
                mChart.invalidate();
                break;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected float getRandom(float range, float startsfrom) {
        return (float) (Math.random() * range) + startsfrom;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.move_left_in_activity, R.anim.move_right_out_activity);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the source code for [CombinedChartRenderer](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/CombinedChartRenderer.java) and for [BarLineChartBase](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/charts/BarLineChartBase.java).

The base renderer draws the *data* first. For `CombinedChartRenderer`, this means iterating through all of the sub-renderers and drawing their *data* (lines for the `LineChart` and bubbles for the `BubbleChart`).

After that, the base renderer will render the *extras*. For `CombinedChartRenderer`, this means iterating through all of the sub-renderers and drawing their *extras*.

Because the circles in the LineChart are *extras* they are drawn after all the data. This means that you will have to find some way to rearrange the order of rendering to meet the requirement. You could start by subclassing `CombinedChart` and overriding the `protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method to change the order to meet your custom requirement.

There is a complete solution (including code) to a problem similar to yours in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585175/5241933)