# MP Android Chart "Table" on XAxis (Custom Renderer for XAxis)

Tags: android, xamarin.android, mpandroidchart

Hello I wan't to know if this kind of graphics are possible using MP Android Chart:

[image]

What I really need is to customize the entire XAxis with several other UI Components (In this case 4 TextViews and an ImageView).

I've been trying different solutions like using a RecyclerView with a `BarChart` inside of it's cell but I am not achieving the efficient UI:

[image]

I have also tried to add a ListView below the Chart but I was not able to sync and order the ListView cells according to the Chart.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kind of graphics that you have posted in your picture are certainly possible, although not easy, with MPAndroidChart.

You will have to write your own subclass of `XAxisRenderer`:

```
ViewPortHandler vph = mChart.getViewPortHandler();
XAxisRenderer xAxisRenderer = new CustomXAxisRenderer(vph, mChart.getXAxis(), vph.getTransformer(AxisDependency.LEFT), image);
mChart.setXAxisRenderer(new CustomXAxisRenderer());
```

A very simple proof-of-concept would look something like this:

```
public class CustomXAxisRenderer extends XAxisRenderer {

    Bitmap image;

    public CustomXAxisRenderer(ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, XAxis xAxis, Transformer transformer, Bitmap image) {
        super(viewPortHandler, xAxis, transformer);
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    protected void drawLabels(Canvas c, float pos, MPPointF anchor) {
        //same code as super class
        //then, code to draw the bitmap image on the canvas
        //and, code to draw the extra text
    }
}
```

Please see the following answers for how to scale bitmap images and draw them on the canvas:

[How to make a custom image inside bars in MPAndroidChart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41373250/5241933)

[How to make a custom highlight drawable in MPAndroidChart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41312738/5241933)

When you have a complete solution you are welcome to post it here as an answer. Good luck!

*Note for proof of concept*: overriding `drawLabels` is a little crude. A better solution would extract a separate method from `drawLabels` and make sure it is called in the `draw(Canvas c)` of the superclass. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585175/5241933) if you want to do that.

Comment: Can you, please, elaborate why it is crude to overwrite drawLabels of XAxisRenderer?

Comment: @user3261128 I guess because you are doing something beside drawing the labels in that method and each method should have a single responsibility