# How do MPAndroidChart renderers work and how do I write a custom renderer?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am using the library MPAndroidChart but it doesn't have all of the functionality I want out of the box.

I have heard that it is possible to implement the functionality I want by writing a custom renderer.

I have looked at the [source code for the renderers](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/LineChartRenderer.java) in the MPAndroidChart GitHub repo, but I can't understand the concepts involved.

How do MPAndroidChart renderers work?

What is the high-level procedure for writing a custom renderer?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Understanding Views and Canvas**

First, one should study the [Canvas and Drawables Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html) from the official Android documentation. Particularly, it is important to note that `LineChart`, `BarChart` etc. are subclasses of `View` that display themselves by overriding the `onDraw(Canvas c)` callback of the View superclass. Note also the definition of "canvas":

> A Canvas works for you as a pretense, or interface, to the actual surface upon which your graphics will be drawn — it holds all of your "draw" calls.

When you are working with renderers, you will be dealing with the functionality for drawing lines, bars, etc. on the canvas.

**Translation between values on the chart and pixels on the canvas**

Points on the chart are specified as x and y values with respect to the units on the chart. For example, in the chart below, the centre of the first bar is at `x = 0`. The first bar has the y-value of `52.28`.

[image: an MPAndroidChart barchart]

This clearly does not correspond to the pixel co-ordinates on the canvas. On the canvas, `x = 0` on the canvas would be a left-most pixel which are clearly blank. Likewise, because pixels enumeration starts from the top as `y = 0`, the tip of the bar is clearly not at `52.28` (the y-value on the chart). If we use Developer options/Pointer location we can see that the tip of the first bar is approximately `x = 165` and `y = 1150`.

A [`Transformer`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.2/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/utils/Transformer.html) is responsible for converting chart values to pixel (on-screen) co-ordinates and vice-versa. A common pattern in renderers is to perform calculations using chart values (which are easier to understand) and then at the end use the transformer to apply a transformation for rendering onto the screen.

**View port and bounds**

A view port is a window i.e., a bounded area on the chart. View ports are used to determine which part of the chart the user can currently see. Each chart has a [`ViewPortHandler`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.2/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/utils/ViewPortHandler.html) that encapsulates the functionality related to view ports. We can use `ViewPortHandler#isInBoundsLeft(float x)` `isInBoundsRight(float x)` to determine which x values the user can currently see.

In the chart pictured above, the BarChart "knows about" the `BarEntry` for 6 and above but because they are out of bounds and not in the current viewport, 6 and upward are not rendered. Hence, x-values `0` through to `5` are within the current viewport.

**ChartAnimator**

The [`ChartAnimator`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.2/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/animation/ChartAnimator.html) provides an additional transformation to be applied to the chart. Usually this is a simple multiplication. For example, assume we want an animation where the points of the chart start at the bottom and gradually rise to their correct y-value over 1 second. The animator will provide a `phaseY` that is a simple scalar starts at `0.000` at time `0ms` and rises gradually to `1.000` at `1000ms`.

**An example of renderer code**

Now that we understand the basic concepts involved, let's look at some code from [`LineChartRenderer`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/LineChartRenderer.java):

```
protected void drawHorizontalBezier(ILineDataSet dataSet) {

    float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY(); 

    Transformer trans = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.getAxisDependency());

    mXBounds.set(mChart, dataSet);

    cubicPath.reset();

    if (mXBounds.range >= 1) {

        Entry prev = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(mXBounds.min);
        Entry cur = prev;

        // let the spline start
        cubicPath.moveTo(cur.getX(), cur.getY() * phaseY);

        for (int j = mXBounds.min + 1; j <= mXBounds.range + mXBounds.min; j++) {

            prev = cur;
            cur = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j);

            final float cpx = (prev.getX())
                    + (cur.getX() - prev.getX()) / 2.0f;

            cubicPath.cubicTo(
                    cpx, prev.getY() * phaseY,
                    cpx, cur.getY() * phaseY,
                    cur.getX(), cur.getY() * phaseY);
        }
    }

    // if filled is enabled, close the path
    if (dataSet.isDrawFilledEnabled()) {

        cubicFillPath.reset();
        cubicFillPath.addPath(cubicPath);
        // create a new path, this is bad for performance
        drawCubicFill(mBitmapCanvas, dataSet, cubicFillPath, trans, mXBounds);
    }

    mRenderPaint.setColor(dataSet.getColor());

    mRenderPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    trans.pathValueToPixel(cubicPath);

    mBitmapCanvas.drawPath(cubicPath, mRenderPaint);

    mRenderPaint.setPathEffect(null);
}
```

The first few lines before the `for` loop are the setup for the renderer loop. Note that we obtain the `phaseY` from the ChartAnimator, the Transformer, and calculate the view port bounds.

The `for` loop basically means "for each point that is within the left and right bounds of the view port". There is no point in rendering x-values that cannot be seen.

Within the loop, we get the x-value and y-value for the current entry using `dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j)` and create a path between that and the previous entry. Note how the path are all multiplied by the `phaseY` for animation.

Finally, after the paths have been calculated a transformation is applied with `trans.pathValueToPixel(cubicPath);` and the paths are rendered to the canvas with `mBitmapCanvas.drawPath(cubicPath, mRenderPaint);`

**Writing a custom renderer**

The first step is choosing the correct class to subclass. Note the classes
in the package `com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer` including `XAxisRenderer` and `LineChartRenderer` etc. Once you create a subclass, you can simply override the appropriate method. As per the example code above, we would override `void drawHorizontalBezier(ILineDataSet dataSet)` without calling `super` (so as to not invoke the rendering stage twice) and replace it with the functionality we want. If you're doing it right, the overridden method should look at least a little bit like the method you are overriding:

1. Obtaining a handle on the transformer, animator, and bounds
2. Looping through the visible x-values (the x-values that are within the view port bounds)
3. Preparing points to render in chart values
4. Transforming the points into pixels on the canvas
5. Using the `Canvas` class methods to draw on the canvas

You should study the methods in the [Canvas class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) (`drawBitmap` etc.) to see what operations you are allowed to perform in the renderer loop.

If the method that you need to override is not exposed, you may have to subclass a base renderer like [`LineRadarRenderer`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/LineChartRenderer.java) to achieve the desired functionality.

Once you have engineered the renderer subclass you want, you can consume it easily with the `Chart#setRenderer(DataRenderer renderer)` or `BarLineChartBase#setXAxisRenderer(XAxisRenderer renderer)` and other methods.

Comment: When implement custom render for line chart it stops library animation. Do you know what could be the reason?