# MPAndroidChart draw dash line from XAxis Line to Data Point

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm trying to make a chart in Android like this image below. (I will call it is Chart Design)
[image: Chart Design]

But I cant custom MPAndroidChart like this design, because I dont know how to draw a dash line from Data Point to XAxis Line. And here is my chart that has customized.
[image: My Chart]

And beside main question, i have another question: how to draw Data Point circle like Chart Design ?

Thanks for your reading, if i have a mistake about grammar, please forgive me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While gridlines are provided from the current API:

```
myChart.getAxisLeft().setDrawGridLines(true);
myChart.getAxisRight().setDrawGridLines(true);
```

There is no API method to draw a line from the x-axis directly to a point on the chart. For this, you would probably have to write a custom renderer extending the appropriate `AxisRenderer` or `LineChartRenderer`. Please see [How do MPAndroidChart renderers work and how do I write a custom renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443787/how-do-mpandroidchart-renderers-work-and-how-do-i-write-a-custom-renderer) for how to do that.

In order to get the points to appear as circles, you simply have to enable drawing circles on your DataSet as in the following code:

```
set1 = new LineDataSet(values, "DataSet 1");
set1.setDrawCircles(true);
set1.setCircleColor(Color.BLACK);
set1.setCircleRadius(3f);
set1.setDrawCircleHole(false);
```