# BarChart and LineChart label positions mismatch

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

The BarChart x-axis value label position and the LineChart x-axis value label position mismatch slightly. What can I do to fix this?

[image: an anmiated gif of a bar chart and a line chart]

[image: mismatched labels on the x-axis]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, I find that the mismatch is barely noticeable and if you hadn't have pointed it out I would not have seen it.

You can tweak the offset of the x-values using [`XAxis#setXOffset(float f)`](https://jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.0.2/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/components/XAxis.html):

```
mChart.getXAxis().setXOffset(10f);
```

Use a negative offset (e.g., `-10f`) if you want to move the labels in the opposite direction.

If you want to tweak the offset of the value on the LineChart it is a bit more complicated - you would have to subclass `LineChartRenderer` and override the method `drawValues`.

Please see [How do MPAndroidChart renderers work and how do I write a custom renderer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443787/how-do-mpandroidchart-renderers-work-and-how-do-i-write-a-custom-renderer) if you wish to attempt that.

Comment: I have not resolved it yet, so I ask you to contact me again .I've added some photos.

Comment: I used this         lineChart.getXAxis().setSpaceMin(0.5f);
        lineChart.getXAxis().setSpaceMax(0.5f);

Comment: Is that really possible?