# MpChart Draw icons as labels in Xaxis of bar chart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

[image]Hi I would like to draw icons in xaxis of the bar chart instead of values. Like the chart below

Answer (score 14, accepted):

you have to create your own custom renderer and apply it to your chart. Here's a rough implementation.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.sauvik.samplegraphs.MainActivity">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
        android:id="@+id/chart1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BarChart mChart;
    int val[] = {3, 2, 7, 3, 4, 8};
    ArrayList<Bitmap> imageList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_grade);
        imageList.add(bitmap);
        imageList.add(bitmap);
        imageList.add(bitmap);
        imageList.add(bitmap);
        imageList.add(bitmap);
        imageList.add(bitmap);

        mChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart1);

        mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
        mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
        mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        mChart.setPinchZoom(false);
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);


        XAxis xAxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xAxis.setLabelCount(7);
        xAxis.setDrawLabels(false);


        YAxis leftAxis = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        leftAxis.setAxisLineColor(Color.WHITE);
        leftAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        leftAxis.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART);
        leftAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f); // this replaces setStartAtZero(true)

        YAxis rightAxis = mChart.getAxisRight();
        rightAxis.setEnabled(false);
        Legend l = mChart.getLegend();
        l.setEnabled(false);
        setData();

    }

    private void setData() {

        ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();
        for (int i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
            yVals1.add(new BarEntry(i, val[i]));
        }

        BarDataSet set1;

        set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "");

        set1.setColors(Color.BLUE);
        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<IBarDataSet>();
        dataSets.add(set1);

        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
        data.setDrawValues(false);
        mChart.setData(data);
        mChart.setScaleEnabled(false);
        mChart.setRenderer(new BarChartCustomRenderer(mChart, mChart.getAnimator(), mChart.getViewPortHandler(), imageList, this));
        mChart.setExtraOffsets(0, 0, 0, 20);

    }

}
```

**CUSTOM RENDERER**

```
public class BarChartCustomRenderer extends BarChartRenderer {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> imageList;

    public BarChartCustomRenderer(BarDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, ArrayList<Bitmap> imageList, Context context) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
        this.context = context;
        this.imageList = imageList;
    }

    @Override
    public void drawValues(Canvas c) {
        List<IBarDataSet> dataSets = mChart.getBarData().getDataSets();
        final float valueOffsetPlus = Utils.convertDpToPixel(22f);
        float negOffset;

        for (int i = 0; i < mChart.getBarData().getDataSetCount(); i++) {

            IBarDataSet dataSet = dataSets.get(i);
            applyValueTextStyle(dataSet);
            float valueTextHeight = Utils.calcTextHeight(mValuePaint, "8");
            negOffset = valueTextHeight + valueOffsetPlus;

            BarBuffer buffer = mBarBuffers[i];

            float left, right, top, bottom;

            for (int j = 0; j < buffer.buffer.length * mAnimator.getPhaseX(); j += 4) {

                left = buffer.buffer[j];
                right = buffer.buffer[j + 2];
                top = buffer.buffer[j + 1];
                bottom = buffer.buffer[j + 3];

                float x = (left + right) / 2f;

                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(x))
                    break;

                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsY(top) || !mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(x))
                    continue;

                BarEntry entry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j / 4);
                float val = entry.getY();
                mValuePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
                if (val > 0) {

                    drawValue(c, dataSet.getValueFormatter(), val, entry, i, x,
                            (bottom + negOffset),
                            dataSet.getValueTextColor(j / 4));
                }

                Bitmap bitmap = imageList.get(j / 4);

                if (bitmap != null) {
                    Bitmap scaledBitmap = getScaledBitmap(bitmap);
                    c.drawBitmap(scaledBitmap, x - scaledBitmap.getWidth() / 2f, (bottom + 0.5f * negOffset) - scaledBitmap.getWidth() / 2f, null);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private Bitmap getScaledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        int width = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_18);
        int height = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.dimen_18);
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
    }


}
```

**RESULT**

[image]

You can replace the stars with your own images.

If you want to know how custom renderer works
Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443787/how-do-mpandroidchart-renderers-work-and-how-do-i-write-a-custom-renderer)

Comment: nice answer +1!

Comment: Do you have a solution for linecharts?

Comment: @felipe.rce it's the same concept.. you have to create a class that extends LineChartRenderer

Comment: @sauvik can you help for my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58503297/line-graph-like-google-weather-graph-in-android

Comment: drawValue(c, dataSet.getValueFormatter(), val, entry, i, x,
                            (bottom + negOffset),
                            dataSet.getValueTextColor(j / 4));

is creating problem.... Can you also mention imports?

Answer (score 0):

I have found how to do it extremely easy:

Add another data set with values set to -1, and provide a drawable upon creating that entry: `new Entry(i, value, icon)`

Use `setStartAtZero(false)` to enable drawing of negative values.
Set data set color to transparent in order to make this dataSet invisible to user.

I admit, that this is pretty hacky solution, but it is easy and doesn't require copy pasting and rewriting code form the lib, so it is easier to maintain updated.

Answer (score 0):

Based on sauvik's answer, I have written an updated version and in Kotlin, for MPAndroidChart v3.1.0. The implementation from sauvik doesn't seem to work with the current version.

The complete Renderer class can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/meyerlasse/d560a7be32dfbcefa457c15f1ea6607f).

And it is used like this (from inside a BarChart subclass):

```
init {
    renderer = BarChartIconRenderer(this, animator, viewPortHandler,
        mBarXAxisIcons, context)
}
```

... with `mBarXAxisIcons` being an `ArrayList<Bitmap>` that you add your bitmaps to.

Additionally, you need to add a dimension `barchart_icon_size`, or customize the `getScaledBitmap` function in the class linked above.

There is one problem with the renderer: the labels on top of the bars are drawn a bit higher than usual, I don't know why yet, but trying to find out and will update this answer accordingly.

[image]