# line graph like google weather graph

Tags: android, user-interface, mpandroidchart, weather, linegraph

I have UI requirement with ling graph, the graph will be have icons above xaxis  just like google weather app UI. Following image is reference.

[image]

Like above image wee need to display icons for the graph.I have previously used MPAndroidChart. I have tried different concepts available in google and SO. still unable achieve this UI.

I have followed following articles

[To show icons in bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45114123/mpchart-draw-icons-as-labels-in-xaxis-of-bar-chart)

[When any value click showing icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31201874/mpandroidchart-linechart-custom-highlight-drawable)

If anyone knows how to implement this UI, help me out.

Comment: Did you try using canvas along with horizontal recyclerview?

Comment: @Karrthik i need graph also if u see the image based on value it will up and down with recyclerview we can't create the difference.

Comment: Actually we can do it using canvas, dividing the height into equal parts using temperature vertically for each item, selecting the part for each recyclerview item based on the temperture and drawing a border accordingly filling the below space with that particular color.

Comment: Give me two days, I will try this out and will let you know.

Comment: @Karrthik Tq for ur help , in the meanwhile can you give me little bit more explanation so that from my end i will also try.

Comment: In a recycler view try to divide height into equal parts based on the temperatures which is along the y-axis. and dates will be along x-axis. you know the previous day and previous day temperature and you will find the co ordinates (x and y). Get the current day and current day temperature, you will find the next co ordinates where you need to draw a border. And fill the inner part with a different color. Do it for each day.

Comment: @Karrthik can you help me regarding this problem, i had tried ur suggestion unable to achieve it.