# How to set different colour for each staked value of StackedBarChart

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

[image]

I am using MPAndroidChart library and my requirement is to show stack value in stack color as given in picture and also not above the bar but left and right for the alternate stack.

I have tried like this way but it didn't work

```
          set.setValueTextColors(colorList);
```

It's giving one color for one complete bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used a custom renderer to fix the issue

Here is the code

**Chart creation**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mp_android_stacked_bar_chart);
        barChart = (BarChart) this.findViewById(R.id.bar_chart);

        float[] val1 = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70};
        float[] val2 = {70, 60, 50, 40, 30, 20, 10};

        ArrayList<BarEntry> yVals1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

        for (int i = 0; i < val1.length; i++) {
            yVals1.add(new BarEntry(i, new float[]{val1[i], val2[i]}));
        }

        barChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        barChart.setPinchZoom(false);      // scaling can now only be done on x- and y-axis separately
        barChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
        barChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
        barChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(true);
        barChart.setHighlightFullBarEnabled(false);
        barChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

        YAxis yAxis = barChart.getAxisLeft();       // change the position of the y-labels
        yAxis.setAxisMinimum(0f);
        yAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);

        XAxis xAxis = barChart.getXAxis();
        xAxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
        xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false);

        ArrayList<Integer> colorList = new ArrayList<>();
        colorList.add(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
        colorList.add(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));

        barChart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
        barChart.setRenderer(new StackedBarChartRenderer(barChart, barChart.getAnimator(), barChart.getViewPortHandler(), colorList));



        BarDataSet set1 = new BarDataSet(yVals1, "");
        set1.setColors(colorList);
        ArrayList<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();



        dataSets.add(set1);
        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
        barChart.setData(data);
        barChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(4f);
        barChart.invalidate();
    }
```

These are important lines in the above code. Here we are setting the our own renderer class for the graph where we pass the required colorList

```
    ArrayList<Integer> colorList = new ArrayList<>();
    colorList.add(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    colorList.add(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.colorAccent));
    barChart.setRenderer(new StackedBarChartRenderer(barChart, barChart.getAnimator(), barChart.getViewPortHandler(), colorList));
```

**RENDERER**

```
public class StackedBarChartRenderer extends BarChartRenderer {

    private ArrayList<Integer> colorList;
    private int index = 0;
    private int numOfColors;

    public StackedBarChartRenderer(BarDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, ArrayList<Integer> colorList) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
        this.colorList = colorList;
        this.numOfColors = colorList.size();
    }

        public void drawValue(Canvas c, IValueFormatter formatter, float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, float x, float y, int color) {
            mValuePaint.setColor(colorList.get(index));
            if(value != 0){
            c.drawText(formatter.getFormattedValue(value, entry, dataSetIndex, mViewPortHandler), x, y, mValuePaint);
           }
            index = ((index + 1) % (numOfColors));
        }
    }
```

In the above code we are overriding the necessary methods and iterating through the colorList in a cicular manner. You may have to change the logic
of the drawValue() function to suit your requirements.

To know more about how custom renderer works, check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443787/how-do-mpandroidchart-renderers-work-and-how-do-i-write-a-custom-renderer)

**Result**

[image]

**EDIT**

```
@Override
    public void drawValues(Canvas c) {

        // if values are drawn
        if (isDrawingValuesAllowed(mChart)) {

            List<IBarDataSet> dataSets = mChart.getBarData().getDataSets();

            final float valueOffsetPlus = Utils.convertDpToPixel(4.5f);
            float posOffset = 0f;
            float negOffset = 0f;
            boolean drawValueAboveBar = mChart.isDrawValueAboveBarEnabled();

            for (int i = 0; i < mChart.getBarData().getDataSetCount(); i++) {

                IBarDataSet dataSet = dataSets.get(i);

                if (!shouldDrawValues(dataSet))
                    continue;

                // apply the text-styling defined by the DataSet
                applyValueTextStyle(dataSet);

                boolean isInverted = mChart.isInverted(dataSet.getAxisDependency());

                // calculate the correct offset depending on the draw position of
                // the value
                float valueTextHeight = Utils.calcTextHeight(mValuePaint, "8");
                posOffset = (drawValueAboveBar ? -valueOffsetPlus : valueTextHeight + valueOffsetPlus);
                negOffset = (drawValueAboveBar ? valueTextHeight + valueOffsetPlus : -valueOffsetPlus);

                if (isInverted) {
                    posOffset = -posOffset - valueTextHeight;
                    negOffset = -negOffset - valueTextHeight;
                }

                // get the buffer
                BarBuffer buffer = mBarBuffers[i];

                final float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();

                MPPointF iconsOffset = MPPointF.getInstance(dataSet.getIconsOffset());
                iconsOffset.x = Utils.convertDpToPixel(iconsOffset.x);
                iconsOffset.y = Utils.convertDpToPixel(iconsOffset.y);

                // if only single values are drawn (sum)
                if (!dataSet.isStacked()) {

                    for (int j = 0; j < buffer.buffer.length * mAnimator.getPhaseX(); j += 4) {

                        float x = (buffer.buffer[j] + buffer.buffer[j + 2]) / 2f;

                        if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(x))
                            break;

                        if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsY(buffer.buffer[j + 1])
                                || !mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(x))
                            continue;

                        BarEntry entry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(j / 4);
                        float val = entry.getY();

                        if (dataSet.isDrawValuesEnabled()) {
                            drawValue(c, dataSet.getValueFormatter(), val, entry, i, x,
                                    val >= 0 ?
                                            (buffer.buffer[j + 1] + posOffset) :
                                            (buffer.buffer[j + 3] + negOffset),
                                    dataSet.getValueTextColor(j / 4));
                        }

                        if (entry.getIcon() != null && dataSet.isDrawIconsEnabled()) {

                            Drawable icon = entry.getIcon();

                            float px = x;
                            float py = val >= 0 ?
                                    (buffer.buffer[j + 1] + posOffset) :
                                    (buffer.buffer[j + 3] + negOffset);

                            px += iconsOffset.x;
                            py += iconsOffset.y;

                            Utils.drawImage(
                                    c,
                                    icon,
                                    (int)px,
                                    (int)py,
                                    icon.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                                    icon.getIntrinsicHeight());
                        }
                    }

                    // if we have stacks
                } else {

                    Transformer trans = mChart.getTransformer(dataSet.getAxisDependency());

                    int bufferIndex = 0;
                    int index = 0;

                    while (index < dataSet.getEntryCount() * mAnimator.getPhaseX()) {

                        BarEntry entry = dataSet.getEntryForIndex(index);

                        float[] vals = entry.getYVals();
                        float x = (buffer.buffer[bufferIndex] + buffer.buffer[bufferIndex + 2]) / 2f;

                        int color = dataSet.getValueTextColor(index);

                        // we still draw stacked bars, but there is one
                        // non-stacked
                        // in between
                        if (vals == null) {

                            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(x))
                                break;

                            if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsY(buffer.buffer[bufferIndex + 1])
                                    || !mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(x))
                                continue;

                            if (dataSet.isDrawValuesEnabled()) {
                                drawValue(c, dataSet.getValueFormatter(), entry.getY(), entry, i, x,
                                        buffer.buffer[bufferIndex + 1] +
                                                (entry.getY() >= 0 ? posOffset : negOffset),
                                        color);
                            }

                            if (entry.getIcon() != null && dataSet.isDrawIconsEnabled()) {

                                Drawable icon = entry.getIcon();

                                float px = x;
                                float py = buffer.buffer[bufferIndex + 1] +
                                        (entry.getY() >= 0 ? posOffset : negOffset);

                                px += iconsOffset.x;
                                py += iconsOffset.y;

                                Utils.drawImage(
                                        c,
                                        icon,
                                        (int)px,
                                        (int)py,
                                        icon.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                                        icon.getIntrinsicHeight());
                            }

                            // draw stack values
                        } else {

                            float[] transformed = new float[vals.length * 2];

                            float posY = 0f;
                            float negY = -entry.getNegativeSum();

                            for (int k = 0, idx = 0; k < transformed.length; k += 2, idx++) {

                                float value = vals[idx];
                                float y;

                                if (value == 0.0f && (posY == 0.0f || negY == 0.0f)) {
                                    // Take care of the situation of a 0.0 value, which overlaps a non-zero bar
                                    y = value;
                                } else if (value >= 0.0f) {
                                    posY += value;
                                    y = posY;
                                } else {
                                    y = negY;
                                    negY -= value;
                                }

                                transformed[k + 1] = y * phaseY;
                            }

                            trans.pointValuesToPixel(transformed);

                            for (int k = 0; k < transformed.length; k += 2) {

                                final float val = vals[k / 2];
                                final boolean drawBelow =
                                        (val == 0.0f && negY == 0.0f && posY > 0.0f) ||
                                                val < 0.0f;
                                float y = transformed[k + 1]
                                        + (drawBelow ? negOffset : posOffset);

                                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsRight(x))
                                    break;

                                if(val == 0){
                                    drawValue(c,
                                            dataSet.getValueFormatter(),
                                            vals[k / 2],
                                            entry,
                                            i,
                                            x,
                                            y,
                                            color);
                                }

                                if (!mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsY(y)
                                        || !mViewPortHandler.isInBoundsLeft(x))
                                    continue;

                                if (dataSet.isDrawValuesEnabled()) {
                                    drawValue(c,
                                            dataSet.getValueFormatter(),
                                            vals[k / 2],
                                            entry,
                                            i,
                                            x,
                                            y,
                                            color);
                                }

                                if (entry.getIcon() != null && dataSet.isDrawIconsEnabled()) {

                                    Drawable icon = entry.getIcon();

                                    Utils.drawImage(
                                            c,
                                            icon,
                                            (int)(x + iconsOffset.x),
                                            (int)(y + iconsOffset.y),
                                            icon.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                                            icon.getIntrinsicHeight());
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        bufferIndex = vals == null ? bufferIndex + 4 : bufferIndex + 4 * vals.length;
                        index++;
                    }
                }

                MPPointF.recycleInstance(iconsOffset);
            }
        }
    }
```

Add this function to your custom render pick up the proper color even if some of your values are 0 in the stacked graph. This above function is exactly same as the default implementation expect for the following part :

```
                           if(val == 0){
                                    drawValue(c,
                                            dataSet.getValueFormatter(),
                                            vals[k / 2],
                                            entry,
                                            i,
                                            x,
                                            y,
                                            color);
                               }
```

Comment: This answer is correct and should be granted the bounty

Comment: @amarok its working for if all stack value is greater than 0 and stack height is enough to render value but in other case right color is not picked for the value. Its happening because we are dependent on index value that is wrong. I think this draw value is not getting called for all the stack in this case. Can you tell me how to resolve this issue. Thanks

Comment: I was testing on this data  float[][] values = {{1, 20, 30,8}, {5, 0, 15,56}, {0, 3, 50,15},{30, 20, 50,56}};

Comment: @PawanGupta I have updated the answer. Several other use cases might come up. You can always edit the render class to meet the requirements

Comment: @amarok Thanks a lot !! You saved day.

Comment: @amarok I've tried this, but the colours are all the same. How is the 'color' argument being used in the drawValue function? It doesn't seem to get used, nor passed on.