# MPAndroidChart BarChart - Vertical values inside of bars

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

I am using the `MPAndroidChart` library for the bar chart, In that, I have used `chart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false)` to set bar values inside of bars, now I want to display the values vertically inside of bars.

Please help..Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

first make this false

```
mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
```

then enable draw values for your data set

```
barDataSet.setDrawValues(true);
```

Since you need to rotate the text as well.. you have to implement a custom renderer for your chart. If you want to know how renderer works, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443787/how-do-mpandroidchart-renderers-work-and-how-do-i-write-a-custom-renderer)

I have provided a sample implementation below. You can modify it to control the position of the text as it suits you.

**Custom Renderer**

```
public class BarChartCustomRenderer extends BarChartRenderer {

    public BarChartCustomRenderer(BarDataProvider chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
    }

    public void drawValue(Canvas c, IValueFormatter formatter, float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, float x, float y, int color) {
        mValuePaint.setColor(color);
        c.save();
        c.rotate(90f, x, y);
        Log.d("here", formatter.getFormattedValue(value, entry, dataSetIndex, mViewPortHandler) );
        c.drawText(formatter.getFormattedValue(value, entry, dataSetIndex, mViewPortHandler), x, y, mValuePaint);
        c.restore();
    }
}
```

**Chart Code**

```
        BarChart mChart = (BarChart) findViewById(R.id.barChart);
        mChart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
        mChart.setDrawValueAboveBar(false);
        mChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
        mChart.setDrawGridBackground(false);

        //**add renderer**
        BarChartCustomRenderer barChartCustomRenderer = new BarChartCustomRenderer(mChart, mChart.getAnimator(),   mChart.getViewPortHandler());
        mChart.setRenderer(barChartCustomRenderer);


        XAxis xaxis = mChart.getXAxis();
        xaxis.setDrawGridLines(false);
        xaxis.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
        xaxis.setGranularity(0.5f);
        xaxis.setGranularityEnabled(true);
        xaxis.setDrawLabels(true);
        xaxis.setDrawAxisLine(false);

        YAxis yAxisLeft = mChart.getAxisLeft();
        yAxisLeft.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.INSIDE_CHART);
        yAxisLeft.setDrawGridLines(false);
        yAxisLeft.setDrawAxisLine(false);
        yAxisLeft.setEnabled(false);

        mChart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);

        Legend legend = mChart.getLegend();
        legend.setEnabled(false);

        ArrayList<BarEntry> valueSet1 = new ArrayList<BarEntry>();

        ArrayList<String> ylabels = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
            BarEntry entry = new BarEntry(i, (i + 1) * 2);
            valueSet1.add(entry);
            ylabels.add(" " + i);
        }

        List<IBarDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();
        BarDataSet barDataSet = new BarDataSet(valueSet1, " ");
        barDataSet.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        barDataSet.setDrawValues(true);
        dataSets.add(barDataSet);


        BarData data = new BarData(dataSets);
        data.setBarWidth(0.4f);
        data.setValueTextSize(10f);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        mChart.setData(data);
        mChart.setFitBars(true);
        mChart.invalidate();
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: Yes..I have used both lines in my code, but I want to show that values vertically on the bar.

Comment: see the picture.. don't you want this result ?

Comment: Yes, It is correct, but values like 2.0,4.0, etc should be vertically shown, because in my case it is 4 to 5 digit long.

Comment: Your updated answer is working fine for BarChartRenderer, but there is the same case for CombinedChartRenderer...It is not working for CombinedChartRenderer. Thanks for your response.

Comment: @Manoj273 did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyCustomRenderer(
    chart: BarDataProvider, animator: ChartAnimator, viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler
) : HorizontalBarChartRenderer(chart, animator, viewPortHandler) {

    override fun drawValue(c: Canvas, valueText: String, x: Float, y: Float, color: Int) {
        mValuePaint.color = color
        val xPoint = Utils.convertDpToPixel(26f)
        val yPoint = Utils.convertDpToPixel(16f)
        c.drawText(valueText, xPoint , yPoint , mValuePaint)
    }
}
```