# MPAndroidChart with custom image

Tags: java, android, charts, mpandroidchart

I am working on making this layout which is a layout contains a chart with custom image. I assume that this is a bar chart with custom image on it.

Every 10 values equal to one bottle image. I'm planning to use MPAndroidChart but seems that i have to make my own customRenderer. but i dont know how to do it.

this is the design of the layout [Chart With Custom Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjA6o.png)

Can anyone please show me an example?

Comment: Hi! There is already a question about how to make a custom renderer in MPAndroidChart. As well as some examples. Please have a play with those first to see if they start you off in the right direction

Comment: thank you for the answer, i've tried to looking for it but i found nothing. would you like to give me the link?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43443787/how-do-mpandroidchart-renderers-work-and-how-do-i-write-a-custom-renderer#43443788